# Installing applications with different user accounts on linux

Tags: linux, access-control, unix

I have basic question about installing applications on Linux operating system, using the Oracle database as an example. When installing the Oracle database package, I created a user called `ora112`, a group called `dba`, and added the user to that group.

So my question is, if the `ora112` user's umask is set to 077, then no other users will be able to configure the Oracle database. Why do we need to follow this practice? Is it a accepted procedure in application installation on Linux. Please share your experience with me.

Similarly, if I install java in this way, then will application belonging to different user accounts be prevented from running java because of this access restriction.

Answer (score 4):

There is no standard method for installing applications. Most applications will set themselves up such that their config files are only writeable by a single uid. Certainly Oracle does this. You can amend the permissions later - but this usually needs to be reapplied whenever you install upgrades.

It's good practice to restrict permissions based on a least privilege basis.

It's NOT good practice to share accounts

To resolve this potential conflict where more than one user may require access to run programs / alter data, then the solution is to setup a group containing the users whom require that access and modify the permissions accordingly.

Alternatively you can use sudo - but IMHO the group based solution is neater (preserves uids).